# How can I make a change to a static variable make a change on a Xamarin.Form?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms page and on the page there is a static variable:

```
namespace City
{
    public static class MS
    {
        public static int secs;
    }
}
```

My XAML

```
<Label x:Name="secondsLabel" />
```

My C# code updates like this

```
while ( ) {
    // the code updates the value of secs here in the loop
    MS.secs++;
    secondsLabel.Text = MS.secs.ToString();
}
```

But the value doesn't change on the screen. Is there a way that I can bind to this static integer so that when secs is changed by the C# code then the screen will automatically be updated also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Label x:Name="secondsLabel" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MS.Secs}}" />
```

you can only bind to public properties, so you will need a property in your code behind or VM

```
public static int Secs {
  get {
    return secs;
  }
  set {
    secs = value;
    PropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to have a propertyChanged method? Also I am not sure but my code is doing this: MS.secs++;   so is it okay with the naming or should I change my code to MS.Secs?

Comment: your class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  And yes, you need to update the public Secs property, because that is what we are binding to.

Comment: okay so then are you saying it would be more normal to have the fields in MS with uppercase first?  I'm just trying to do what's most popular.  Can you suggest a PropertyChanged method in the answer.  I want to be sure I get it right.  Thanks

Comment: there are thousands of examples on SO and elsewhere of how to implement INPC.  I'm not going to type up yet another example of that.